# Access peewee's Meta subclass in Model's outer class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, peewee

I'm trying to wrap peewee models and classes into other interface and i want to dynamically assign model to database. I'm using peewee.Proxy class for this, but i don't want to use global variable for making initialization of this proxy available. I wanted to make class method for changing Meta (inner) class of base model, but i get following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'BaseModel' has no attribute 'Meta'
```

Code that i have:

```
import peewee as pw
class BaseModel(pw.Model):
    class Meta:
        database = pw.Proxy()

    @classmethod
    def configure_proxy(cls, database: pw.Database):
        cls.Meta.database.initialize(database)
```

Of course i could access this variable by calling BaseModel.Meta.database but it is less intuitive in my opinion.

Have you got any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Peewee transforms the inner "Meta" class into an object accessible at "ModelClass._meta" after the class is constructed:

Change ".Meta" to "._meta":

```
class BaseModel(pw.Model):
    class Meta:
        database = pw.Proxy()

    @classmethod
    def configure_proxy(cls, database: pw.Database):
        cls._meta.database.initialize(database)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why you are having this problem, and I'd be interested in the full answer.

The problem is with the name `Meta`. I'm guessing there's something by that name defined in `pw.Model` but I haven't been through it all yet.

That said, this (for example) works:

```
import peewee as pw
class BaseModel(pw.Model):
    class MyMeta:
        database = pw.Proxy()

    @classmethod
    def configure_proxy(cls, database: pw.Database):
        cls.MyMeta.database.initialize(database)
```

Comment: See https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/master/peewee.py#L5352. It looks like the metaclass of `pw.Model` removes `Meta` from the dict used to construct the class.